# Expo build:ios fails with "Error while gathering & validating credentials"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I'm trying to run `exp build:ios` and it returns the following error:

```
Running: bash.exe -c PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin /mnt/c/Users/MyName/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_m
odules/exp/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux/traveling-fastlane-1.4.7-linux-x86_64/validate_apple_credentials "USERNAME PASSWORD"  

Error while gathering & validating credentials
04:55:52 [exp] Error: Reason:Unknown reason, raw:"{\"authType\"=>\"sa\"}\naa=11CECD94B0A448A2CA74B798F957D91C; Domain=idmsa.apple.com; Path=/; Secure
; HttpOnly, dslang=US-EN; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, site=USA; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, acn01=ecHGTzyh6KpEMYGK3/n
dp5OBSctZ7OhjWIMEzX9jeHHDdeMxlEYAEHHyjSOfEg==; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Wed, 22-May-2019 01:55:52 GMT; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"
04:55:52 [exp] Reason:Unknown reason, raw:"{\"authType\"=>\"sa\"}\naa=11CECD94B0A448A2CA74B798F957D91C; Domain=idmsa.apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpO
nly, dslang=US-EN; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, site=USA; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, acn01=ecHGTzyh6KpEMYGK3/ndp5OBSc
tZ7OhjWIMEzX9jeHHDdeMxlEYAEHHyjSOfEg==; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Wed, 22-May-2019 01:55:52 GMT; Domain=apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly"
04:55:52
```

I'm trying to build on the following platform:

OS: Windows 10(with WSL Ubuntu 18.04)
Expo: 27.0.2

And have the following on `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "APP_NAME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^6.3.1",
    "exp": "^54.0.0",
    "expo": "^27.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.4.4",
    "npm": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-27.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-twitter": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.12",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

And also `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "APP_NAME",
    "description": "APP_NAME description",
    "slug": "Appname",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "27.0.0",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "androidStatusBar": {
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["ttf", "mp4"]
    },
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "versionCode": 4
    }
  }
}
```

P.S: running `exp build:android` works fine.
What is the cause of this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: for me I received the error trying to view ios account details in Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just connect to https://appleid.apple.com/ or http://itunesconnect.apple.com and accept the privacy update.

[image: apple id privacy]

Comment: What sort of black magic is this!! Why can we just get a proper error message!? (@MoOx you got my vote)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same error on osX today. And after a lot of pain, i figured out it was a terms of service that i needed to accept:

https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=......

once i did that the build started working again.